# Copying an image to clipboard using JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, clipboard

I need to copy an image to clipboard using JavaScript/jquery and I am using the following js to achieve that.

```
function copyImageToClipBoard() {
            var div = document.getElementById('chart1');
            div.contentEditable = true;
            var controlRange;
            if (document.body.createControlRange) {
                controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
                controlRange.addElement(div);
                controlRange.execCommand('Copy');                   
            }
            div.contentEditable = false;
        }
```

It works fine locally in IE. But when I tried to test it from other machines IE, to paste the image into MS word I need to use the Paste Special-> Device Independent Bitmap option, otherwise I cannot see the image pasted.

I was wondering if it has anything to do with the environment of the m/c. If so is there any other option which works anywhere?

Answer (score -3):

Clipboard access on the web is not desirable because of the security implications.

Comment: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

Comment: You could easily show a permissions prompt to satisfy security concerns similar to how Web Notifications shows an a prompt.