# How can I copy rich text contents to the clipboard with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

### Premise

I need help copying rich text to the clipboard using JavaScript. I have searched around and haven't found anything to suit my specific needs.

### Code

```js
function ctrlA1(corp) {
  with(corp) {}
  if (document.all) {
    txt = corp.createTextRange()
    txt.execCommand("Copy")
  } else
    setTimeout("window.status=''", 5000)
}
```

```html
<div id="sc1">hello <br> <b> world </b> </div>
<button onclick="ctrlA1(document.getElementById('sc1') )"></button>
```

### Problem

The aforementioned code isn't working and is resulting in an `object expected error`. Any help is appreciated!
I have seen a library out there called `zeroclipboard`, but would prefer to write my own function.

---

## Edit:

I now have this function to select text on the page. is it possible to write a formula to copy the selected range as is?

```js
function containerSelect(id) {
  containerUnselect();
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(id);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(id);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<label onclick="containerSelect(this); select_all()">
  <p>hello world</p>
  <img src="imagepath.png">
</label>
```

Comment: BTW, ['Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues.'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: Solution with JS only, See http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3

Answer (score -4, accepted):

i searched for a week now and finally found my answer!!!
for those of you looking to copy rich text to the clipboard with javascript, then use the function at the link below, works like a charm.
no need of flash and other stuff suggested :)

[Copying an image to clipboard using JavaScript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743559/copying-an-image-to-clipboard-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: That's for images, not rich text.  And anyway it is IE only :-(

Answer (score 104):

With modern browsers, if you want to **copy rich text** only, there is a very easy solution *without using any packages*, using [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent).[clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData). See http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3.

Here is the source code from the Fiddle:

```html
<button onclick="copyToClip(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML)">
  Copy the stuff
  </button>
  
<div id=foo style="display:none">
  This is some data that is not visible. 
  You can write some JS to generate this data. 
  It can contain rich stuff.  <b> test </b> me <i> also </i>
  <span style="font: 12px consolas; color: green;">Hello world</span> 
  You can use setData to put TWO COPIES into the same clipboard, 
  one that is plain and one that is rich. 
  That way your users can paste into either a
  <ul>
    <li>plain text editor</li>
    <li>or into a rich text editor</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the function:

```js
function copyToClip(str) {
  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
```

As always, you'll need to [ensure compatibility for your target browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData#browser_compatibility).

Note that `execCommand` is deprecated, and the [ClipboardAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) should be preferred. I highly recommend reading this [other answer by @Miriam](/a/77305170/).

Comment: Thank you. I tested this by copying and pasting into Word. It works beautifully on Chrome. It does not seem to work on IE11 at all. On Edge it will paste the text but without formatting.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I didn't test it on IE 11 or edge.  I wonder... if you reverse the two `e.clipboardData.setData` then perhaps you can paste rich text with IE edge... ?   just a thought

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari 11.1.1. Nothing copies, whatever was previously on the clipboard is still there.

Comment: This works for me in FF, Chrome, Edge, and IE11.  IE11 prompts the user if to allow access to the clipboard.  It does not work in Safari.  Another method is required for that, and as far as I can tell you can't copy the "rich text", just plain text.

Comment: You can use a little bit modified code to also provide text-only version for editors that can not render html: http://jsfiddle.net/kt4jdm95/1/

Comment: NB: [`document.execCommand` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Answer (score 12):

This tiny JS plugin copies richtext **without using Flash**:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-js

It's based on https://clipboardjs.com/ - but it's an upgrade in my opinion, because the original only supports plain text.

The code is simple:

```
clipboard.copy({
    "text/html": "<i>Markup</i> <b>text</b>. Paste me into a rich text editor."
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and is indeed simple.

Comment: With modern browsers, if you want COPY RICH TEXT only, there is a very easy solution **without using any packages**.  See https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3/

Comment: @JohnHenckel, that is fantastic! You ought to make it an answer!

Comment: Just to point out that for IE @SFlagg's solution will not copy rich text, but only plain text

Comment: i can't get this working if the rich text contains images.

Comment: I created a functional example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33758293/1762224

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example I tested using the new Clipboard API:

```
const content = '<a href="http://google.com/">test</a>';
const blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/html'});
const clipboardItem = new window.ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blob });
navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem]);
```

Using this method, you can copy html to the clipboard. One useful thing to note is that this can include images (which can be dataURLs). This is the only way I found to paste multiple images to the clipboard.

Comment: This does not work on Firefox.  Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216984/4493592)  in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191780/javascript-copy-string-to-clipboard-as-text-html/74216984#74216984).

Comment: If trying this in the console, it may fail because the document itself doesn't have focus, in which case you might need to put this code in a `setTimeout` so that you have time to move focus back to the document.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple function which uses the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) where it is supported (as I write this, that's everywhere but Firefox), and falls back to the [`document.execCommand("copy")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method [from John Henckel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067769) where it is not (deprecated, but currently works everywhere), in the hope that Firefox will add support for the Clipboard API before it drops support for `execCommand` :)

```js
/** Paste richly formatted text.
 *
 * @param {string} rich - the text formatted as HTML
 * @param {string} plain - a plain text fallback
 */
async function pasteRich(rich, plain) {
  if (typeof ClipboardItem !== "undefined") {
    // Shiny new Clipboard API, not fully supported in Firefox.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#browser_compatibility
    const html = new Blob([rich], { type: "text/html" });
    const text = new Blob([plain], { type: "text/plain" });
    const data = new ClipboardItem({ "text/html": html, "text/plain": text });
    await navigator.clipboard.write([data]);
  } else {
    // Fallback using the deprecated `document.execCommand`.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility
    const cb = e => {
      e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", rich);
      e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", plain);
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    document.addEventListener("copy", cb);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", cb);
  }
}
```

You might also like to try [a proper polyfill for the Clipboard API](https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard-polyfill).

Answer (score 2):

The Document.execCommand() is apparently becoming obsolete:

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand),

There is a new Clipboard API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

There are some examples here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

And also here:
https://web.dev/async-clipboard/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old Flash-based solution. Due to the discontinuation of Flash, it should no longer be used in production environments.

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Comment: The OP mentions zeroclipboard in his question, and I talk about it in my comment.

Comment: i just figured id offer an answer. Since there is no reliable JS method for doing it

Comment: @codenamejames: ok, i tried using the help on ZC and dont think i'm being very successful here. here is my code which isnt working still :(

Comment: <div id="d_clip_button">Copy To Clipboard</div> <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath("ZeroClipboard.swf"); var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button') ); </script> `

Comment: i think it should be more like this ```ZeroClipboard.config({ moviePath: "ZeroClipboard.swf" }); var client = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById('d_clip_button'));```

Comment: @codenamejames that didnt work unfortunately. get an "object doesnt support this method" error. I have another function that selects text/images on the webpage (edited my post above). can i now write a function to copy the selected range?

Comment: @codenamejames the last function i posted works fine, just need to know how to copy that selected text :p

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking for Updated version of working code, here it is with Clipboard API

```
export async function copyHTMLasRichText({ htmlString }) {
    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.write([
            new ClipboardItem({
                "text/html": new Blob([htmlString], { type: "text/html" }),
                "text/plain": new Blob([htmlString], { type: "text/plain" })
            })
        ]);
        toast('Copied to clipboard');
    } catch(e) {
        toast.error('Could not copy');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified (and renamed) version of @Miriam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77305170/10237506), using `no-undef` workaround for **React JS** apps as discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/w8ka67/comment/ihpv2zl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

```js
/** Copy richly formatted text to clipboard.
 *
 * @param {string} rich - the text formatted as HTML
 */
async function copyRichToClip(rich) {
  // a plain text fallback - here we default to rich-text
  const plain = rich;

  if (typeof ClipboardItem !== "undefined") {
    // Shiny new Clipboard API, not fully supported in Firefox.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#browser_compatibility
    const html = new Blob([rich], { type: "text/html" });
    const text = new Blob([plain], { type: "text/plain" });
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const data = new ClipboardItem({ "text/html": html, "text/plain": text });
    await navigator.clipboard.write([data]);
  } else {
    // Fallback using the deprecated `document.execCommand`.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#browser_compatibility
    function listener(e) {
      e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", rich);
      e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", plain);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
  }
}
```

BTW, this is the workaround for ESLint and React Apps:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
```

It gets rid of this error in browser:

[image]