# How to copy using clipboard.js with dynamic content and triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard, clipboard.js

After a click on `.fw-code-copy-button` I would like to copy source code from it's nearest container.
`.fw-code-copy-button`-s are created dynamically, after user click dedicated "view source" button.

Html for example button:

```
<span class="fw-code-copy">
  <span class="fw-code-copy-button" data-clipboard-text="...">copy</span>
</span>
```

This is how i trigger click event, and define the source code to be copied to clipboard:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fw-code-copy-button", function(){
  var source = $(this).closest(".fw-code-copy").next("code").text();
});
```

And this is how [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/) triggers it's copy event

```
new Clipboard(".fw-code-copy-button", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    return source; // source should somehow be copied from scope above it
  }
});
```

Whenever i click anywhere on the website, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing required attributes, use either "target" or "text"
```

But first of all I don't want to define text to be copied in `data-clipboard-text="..."`
and secondly `data-clipboard-text` is defined with `"..."` as it's value.

If someone would pay a second i would be very grateful.

**[edit]** I have written jsFiddle for demonstration, and suprisingly UncaughtError disappeared, but i still need to move `source` code from  onClick to Clipboard scope.

https://jsfiddle.net/2rjbtg0c/1/

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Ok I will write a fiddle for this right now, since the code fragments i pasted use lot of dependencies in original code.

Comment: I believe you can either have the data attribute on the element or defined as a method on your `Clipboard` instance, but not both. I would remove the attribute.

Comment: @xxxmatko I have added jsfiddle for demonstration.

Comment: I have run the fiddle and I do not see any error.

Comment: @xxxmatko yeah i found the reason, it was `new Clipboard("div");` defined somewhere else and i forgot to remove it, it's not in the fiddle, so the error doesn't appear too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your original code:

```
 new Clipboard(".fw-code-copy-button", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    return $(trigger).closest(".fw-code-copy").next("code").text(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: That's it. Tested in my project and it's working right now. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The trigger is the button you clicked. Get the parent and then return the text inside the code block. You will also need to trim any leading and trailing white-space.

## Demo

This grabs text inside a code block as in your included example

```js
new Clipboard(".fw-code-copy-button", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    return $(trigger).parent().find('code').first().text().trim();
  }
});
```

```css
.fw-code-copy {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFE;
  border: thin solid #FF0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.fw-code-copy-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: thin solid #777;
  background: #800080;
  color: #FFF;
}
.fw-code-copy-button:hover {
  border: thin solid #DDD;
  background: #992699;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<span class="fw-code-copy">
  <span class="fw-code-copy-button">Copy</span>
  <code>&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;style-1.css&quot;&gt;</code>
</span>
<span class="fw-code-copy">
  <span class="fw-code-copy-button">Copy</span>
  <code>&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;style-2.css&quot;&gt;</code>
</span>
<span class="fw-code-copy">
  <span class="fw-code-copy-button">Copy</span>
  <code>&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;style-3.css&quot;&gt;</code>
</span>
```

Comment: Yeah. I'm going to completely remove `document onclick` and target the source using the trigger element. It's the best answer so far for now.