# update the content of clipboard in prismjs

Tags: javascript, events, clipboard, clipboard.js

I have code snippet, which user can copy to his/her site. I use [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/) to show html code. also it has copy button, so user can copy the code in clipboard, it uses [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/) for this. user can choose between different options(this is the list like `<select><option>..`), which will update the code snippet and also should update the content of clipboard button(here's issue).

here's html

```
<pre class="language-html">
   <code id="code-example">
     <!-- <div class="widget widget-BTC" data-fiat="EUR"></div> -->
   </code>
</pre>
```

after user choose different options, the content of `<code id="code-example">` will be updated (it updates the class name and `data-fiat` attribute)

here's js code which does update:

```
 let block = document.getElementById('code-example');
 block.innerHTML = '<!-- <div class="widget ...';
 Prism.highlightElement(block);
```

the issue is, when I choose other option from select list, it updates html code snippet, but if I click the copy button, it copies the old value, not updated one. I tried different things like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757518/how-to-copy-using-clipboard-js-with-dynamic-content-and-triggers) but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to create another object to update the value. here's solution:

```
new Clipboard('.yourButton', {
text: function(trigger) {
    return '<div>some text</div>';
}
```

});