# Copy Button Preserving Line Breaks

Tags: javascript

I have some very basic Javascript that copies text upon the push of a button. My problem is that it doesnt preserve line breaks:

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
</script>
```

I'd really like something to be able to be added to the above script to avoid making huge changes on the site already.

I've seen things on other posts such as:

```
post.innerHTML = post.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');
```

which in theory would work (i think) but I suck at Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `element` type ? input or textarea?

Comment: [copy rich text to clipboard using js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/javascript-copy-rich-text-contents-to-clipboard)

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041831/copy-to-clipboard-with-break-line/50230647#50230647

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First off, the `<input>` element doesn't preserve line breaks. You can use the `<textarea>` element instead. Since your HTML may contain `<br>` elements instead of line break characters, I would also suggest using jQuery to prepend `\r\n` before each `<br>`.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var text = $(element).clone().find('br').prepend('\r\n').end().text()
  element = $('<textarea>').appendTo('body').val(text).select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  element.remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">Type to edit <br> this text</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('p')">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

Comment: This works great, except for one thing... i have tags in between the text that seems to be causing it to line break also. Can something be added to the above to ignore whenever the following occurs: This is some text <ref class="glowingtext"><span id='followupdot'/></ref> that i would like to all appear on the same line.

Comment: Before `.find('br')`, insert `.find('ref.glowingtext').remove().end()`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

We have adapted the copyToClipboard function to get it to work with our application. The changes were the following:

- change the input to textarea so that the line breaks are passed;
- change the text() function to html() so that the HTML is passed;
- use a regex to replace each HTML br with the linefeed;
- use another regex to strip the remaining HTML. The HTML in our 
  application should only have `<b>` and `<br>` tags, so the simple regex should work, and also handle the odd tag that might be present.

Here is our adapted function, along with comments:

```
// Note: original replace used to strip HTML tags from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string ReactiveRaven.
// However, replaced closing (>|$) with > as I don't understand why the check for $ is there, as it implies that $ is part of an HTML tag.
// Our requirement highly constrains the HTML, to mainly have <br> and <b> tags, so the general objection to parsing HTML with regex
// as at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags community wiki is not applicable.
// BTW, that page is very entertaining!
function copyToClipboard(element)
{
    var $temp = $("<textarea>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    var x = $(element).html().trim().replace(/<br>/g, '\n').replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');
    $temp.val(x).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

Btw, if somebody knows why the regex from the cited page had the (>|$) that we changed to >, we would appreciate gaining the understanding as to why the dollar sign that we removed is needed.