# Javascript CopytoClipboard function only copies 1 line

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP script which will print out a list of items. I wanted to add a button on there which copies the one or more items in the list to the clipboard. I have found a basic Javascript function that seems to work nicely.

However if I get more than 2 lines, the copy function will only copy the first line. How can I do this correctly?

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])){
    echo'<div class =" col-md-6 pull-right"><h3>Tokens you just generated below</h3><br>';
    if((isset($_POST['create']) && ($insert_token && $stmt->rowCount())) >0){
        foreach ($generatedtokens as $tokens){
            $ListTokens = ($tokens['token'].' - '.$tokens['desc'].'<br>');
            echo '<p id="tokens">'.nl2br($ListTokens).'</p>';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['create'])){
            ?>
            <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#tokens')" class ="btn btn-primary">Copy Tokens</button>
            <?php
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(element) {
        var $temp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to get element value with `id` being the same in all `p` tags so it was only copying one line to the clipboard.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var text =  '';
    $('#itemlist p').each(function() {
        text +=  '\r\n' + $(this).html() + '\r\n';
    });
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    input.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dontcopy"> 
<p>Dup Item 1</p>
<p>Dup Item 2</p>
<p>Dup Item 3</p>
<p>Dup Item 4</p>
</div> 
<div id="itemlist"> 
<p>Item 1</p>
<p>Item 2</p>
<p>Item 3</p>
<p>Item 4</p>
</div> 
<button onclick="copyToClipboard();" class ="btn btn-primary">Copy Tokens</button>
```

Thanks for the input @Mr. Greenwoodz

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap template so I should have no problem using JQuery as I believe it is built in. I will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Seems to not be working for me, using Jquery 3.2.1 ...
I have used it in a simple script tag, the copy function just does nothing. IS there anything else required but what code you have supplied here?

Comment: I works, but copies most of the text from the whole page. I tried to add the div id and it still copied everything lol. Progress tho :)

Comment: seems to be copying all P tags

Comment: It's because you are selecting all the p tags with this line: var text = $('p').text(); If you do this instead it should work for only the p tags inside of the itemlist: var text = $('#itemlist p').text();

Comment: @Mr.Greenwoodz - Perfect.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it copies the line breaks?
It is one long line when I paste it.

Comment: I did a quick search and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816349/copy-button-preserving-line-breaks

Comment: Interesting..
The input type does not preserve, but when I change to <textarea> it breaks the whole function. :,(

Comment: Posted an answer using a textarea in the function;)

Comment: This solution seems to be closest to the final goal, just need to get those linebreaks passed over without displaying a <textarea> on the page, I would do it, but I'm pretty sure the hidden option does not work on it.

Comment: Like a Boss! :)

Comment: I used this instead
`text +=  '\r\n' + $(this).html();`
It works and reduces the extra empty line between each.

This has been fun, thanks again! :)

Comment: glad i could help  @JohnMartin

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the example you've posted using a textarea. Now the line breaks are also copied.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="items">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
    </div>

    <button onclick="copyToClipboard();" class ="btn btn-primary">Copy Tokens</button>
    <script>

    function copyToClipboard() 
    {
        var texts = [];
        var text = $('#items p')
        var txtarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        document.body.appendChild(txtarea);

        text.each(function(index, value)
        {
            txtarea.append(value.innerHTML + '\n');
        });

        txtarea.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(txtarea);
    }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks good.
I'm not looking to display a textarea however. I have tried it, but seems that even while in the textarea there is no line breaks between each token...sigh..

Comment: Ive edited my example. Now the items are first added to a textarea and in which i added a break (\n). After that the textarea is selected and copied with breaks. After being copied the textarea is removed.

Comment: Damn I will try it too, the other one works so I will keep that for now, it is too early in the morn, I need to sleep now. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Your welcome;) Have fun dreaming about textarea's and line breaks haha. : )

Comment: No kidding lmao, I think I did dream about it.