# document.execCommand Copying Format from a text and Paste the format

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm using `contenteditable = true` and `document.execCommand` to style the text that the user typed.

The user styles a text block with fill color, italic and bold fonts etc. And just like we do in MS Word, he needs a Copy Format button to copy all styling in a text block, and just go on some other text block, highlight and paste the same styling.

As I understand, there is no function in `document.execCommand` that I can use. Do you know any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Please see this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/javascript-copy-rich-text-contents-to-clipboard). From there you can get this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/km7prgv4/3) :)

Comment: Thansk but I'm not talknig about copying a text with styles, I only want to copy "the styles", and apply the same styles to many text pieces on the page. @C.RaysOfTheSun