# How do I put a link with link text in the copy buffer?

Tags: javascript, html

[This text](https://stackoverflow.com) is a link. How do I put this into the copy buffer (e.g. via `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`) so that when the user pastes it somewhere else it retains the link text as well as the link itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Pichler, Do you want it to be pasted as an html element like in gmail, doc etc or as a simple text in a text field, is there anything that you have tried and the result of same ?

Comment: I want the link to be pasted into other applications such as thunderbird or google docs. I tried to use `navigator.clipboard.writeText('<a href="stackoverflow.com">Link</a>')` which just puts the whole html element in plain text into the copy buffer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript copy rich text contents to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/javascript-copy-rich-text-contents-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

When u use addEventListener, you can extract all information from the event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>

    <script>
        const linkComponent = document.querySelector('.link');

        linkComponent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the default action (going to link)
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(`${event.target.innerHTML} - ${event.path[0].href}`);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ClipboardJs, it work for gmail or other email clients

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <a href="https://google.com">test link</a>
</div>
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#container">Click me</button>
<script>
    let clipboard = new ClipboardJS(".btn", {})
        .on("success", function () {
            console.log('success')
        })
        .on("error", function () {
            console.log('error')
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```