# Copy to clipboard html output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple code to copy some content to clipboard when i click on a specific Div (not an actual button) :

```
$("#myButtonDiv").on("click", function () {
    var myText = ('<p style="color:#ff0000;">content 123</p>')
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(myText);
});
```

However, this will copy the html code to clipboard; is there a way to copy the desired output instead ? (i.e. copy "content 123" in red)

**Note :** to be a little more precise, my variable myText is actually like that :

```
var myText = $('#myContentDiv').html();
```

Where #myContentDiv displays the desired output.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `var myText = $('#myContentDiv').text();` I guess?

Comment: @ChrisG that will not get the color....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: You need to write it to the DOM and select it to copy

Comment: Hi, 
I finally found the answer, a pretty easy solution, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/javascript-copy-rich-text-contents-to-clipboard
Thank you for your help !