# How copy the output of a HTML element that contains text and image?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is copy the result of my HTML code with a clipboard button.

So, I have [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6O7N.png) in the main section of my page, and I want to be able to click in the 'button' of the top corner to **COPY** that entire label and later be able to [paste it into Gmail](https://i.postimg.cc/G38B2Q8f/Screen-Shot-2022-09-24-at-1-14-49-AM.png) **(plis open)**/outlook without any problems with the design.

**Note:** The HTML code that generates the label has 100% compatibility with emails (I used [Can I email?](https://www.caniemail.com)).

Manually would be something like [this action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqN53.png) then crt/cmd + C, but I want to achieve the same process with JS code, it's possible?

HTML code of the entire card (DIV):

```
<div id="card-signature" class="relative min-w-[250px] rounded-2xl mb-8">
            <!-- Button to copy the 'Uber Signature'-->
            <div id="1" class="btn absolute w-[30px] h-[30px] top-0 right-0 p-2 rounded-tr-xl bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" data-view-component="true">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 6.75C0 5.784.784 5 1.75 5h1.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-1.5a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v7.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h7.5a.25.25 0 00.25-.25v-1.5a.75.75 0 011.5 0v1.5A1.75 1.75 0 019.25 16h-7.5A1.75 1.75 0 010 14.25v-7.5z"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 1.75C5 .784 5.784 0 6.75 0h7.5C15.216 0 16 .784 16 1.75v7.5A1.75 1.75 0 0114.25 11h-7.5A1.75 1.75 0 015 9.25v-7.5zm1.75-.25a.25.25 0 00-.25.25v7.5c0 .138.112.25.25.25h7.5a.25.25 0 00.25-.25v-7.5a.25.25 0 00-.25-.25h-7.5z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="p-6 overflow-x-scroll scroll-smooth">
                <!-- SIGNATURE #1 - Joseph Ero -->
                <div id="card1" style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important;">
                    <div style="font-family: Arial, sens-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3;" class="template-template1 is-flipped-false font-family-arial font-size font-family text-color">
                        <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; font-size: inherit;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0 18px 0 0; line-height: 0px;">
                                    <img style="border: 0px; height: 70px; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; min-width: 70px; width: 70px;" src="https://i.postimg.cc/pVCn3TjW/732135.png" alt="Email sender photo" width="70" height="70" class="photo photo-size" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; font-size: inherit;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-weight: 700; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sens-serif; font-size: 15px;" class="name title-color">Joseph Ero</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-top: 6px;">
                                                <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; font-size: inherit;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sens-serif; font-size: 14px; min-width: 108px;" class="phone">+1 500-400-4000</td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="mailto:john.doe@uber.com" style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: underline !important; font-size: 14px !important; font-family: Arial, sens-serif !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important;" class="email">joseph.ero@uber.com</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-top: 6px;">
                                                <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; font-size: inherit;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sens-serif; font-size: 14px; min-width: 236px;" class="address">2200 Blake Street. Denver, CO 80200</td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 11px;"><a href="https://www.uber.com" style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: underline !important; font-size: 14px !important; font-family: Arial, sens-serif !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important;" class="website link-color">uber.com</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                
                        <table border=0 width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; font-size: inherit;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sens-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.3; min-width: 666px;">Wanna know more about our business? <a href="https://www.uber.com/dts" style="color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: underline !important; font-size: 14px !important; font-family: Arial, sens-serif !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important;" class="website link-color">Read our insights to learn more.</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**I tried with:**

(1) Clipboard API process:

```
button.addEventListener('click', handlerClick)

    function handlerClick () {
        const idTarget = this.id
        const cardSelected = document.querySelector(`#card${idTarget}`)

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(cardSelected)
    }
```

**Result:** [object HTMLDivElement].

(2) html2canvas: Doesn't work for my needs.

## Solution

The code below resolve my goal. Useful documentation: Excellent article about [selection and range](https://javascript.info/selection-range#selection-events); [useful example](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/cut-and-copy-commands/); [optional idea](http://help.dottoro.com/ljouisvm.php).

```
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

    button.addEventListener('click', handlerClick)
    function handlerClick () {
        const idTarget = this.id;
        const cardSelected = document.querySelector(`#card${idTarget}`);

        if (document.createRange) {
            // Clear any INITIAL selection 
            const selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();

            // Select all the label (Signature)
            const range = document.createRange();
            const rangeSelected = range.selectNodeContents(cardSelected);
            selection.addRange(range);

            try {
                // Copy all the label selected
                let successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                let msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
                console.log(`Copy email command was ${msg}`);
                // Clear any CURRENT selection (It's optional)
                const selection = window.getSelection();
                selection.removeAllRanges();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Unable to copy');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're selecting the DOM element. That's an object. You should select `innerHTML` instead so you get a serialized string of the html contents instead of the DOM object.

Comment: ^ eg. `cardSelected.innerHTML`

Comment: I understand, but the result is the HTML code and no the label itself that I need to copied in the email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy rich text contents to the clipboard with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934656/how-can-i-copy-rich-text-contents-to-the-clipboard-with-javascript)

Comment: Not really, because I'm just capturing the text and image. I need is capture the text and image (rich text) with the styles applied (output of my HTML/CSS) that's why I need to copy like selecting all my label with my mouse and then copied for emails purposes.