# Copy the image using jquery/javascript and paste them in to word file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a QR Code and an Image in a `div`. I want to copy the QR Code and the Image by clicking a Copy button and then paste them to word file.

Is this possible using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying an image to clipboard using javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743559/copying-an-image-to-clipboard-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. File operations can not be done in JS/Jquery side and its not allowed by browsers(thank god!). Activex can make it possible but I don't think you want that. There the File API of HTML5 but not all browsers support.

My Suggestion would be to create WebMethod/WebService to do something like this, make ajax call to this webservice from your javascript or Jquery. User experience will remain same as you intend.