# Copy text innerHTML of element to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I was try many solutions in stackoverflow, but it not work.([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/5715248) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192073/5715248))

I try it in [Website](http://ln.hako.re/truyen/124-hikaru-ga-chikyuu-ni-itakoro/c6271-phu-chuong-tham-vong-cua-shioriko-boi-vi-gio-em-se-goi-anh-la-onii-chan-duoc-chu) and use [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) for run code (chrome 59.0.3071.104 64bit)

```
<h4 align="center">text data to copy</h4>

var copy_text = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
copy_text.select(); //-> error: select is not a function
```

and

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(copy_text);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand("copy"); //-> clipboard not change
```

Any solution for this?
Thankyou.

---

Edit: I think my problem is page loading (security brower), all solution work with user interactive

Comment: console.log (document.queryCommandSupported('copy')) 
what output do you have with this command?

Comment: it write "true"

Comment: Did you try [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/2419531)?

Comment: @Saravana: `window.getSelection().addRange(range);`  sellect success too.

Comment: Can sellect but can't copy

Answer (score 4):

Here, the first example. https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f. My example is re-written by my needs but You'll get the point :)

```
<div onclick="bufferText()">Миньор Перник!</div>
<script>
   function bufferText() {    
        const el = document.createElement("textarea");
        el.value = event.target.innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(el);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.copybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copy_text = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(copy_text);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="copybtn">Copy</button>
<h4 align="center">text data to copy</h4>
```

But it isn't working if I try to copy not on click, but when the page is loaded

Comment: To call the function on page load you can use jQuery `$.ready()` or if you don't want to use jQuery you can follow these instructions: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: @JoseGomez: `$('document').ready(function()
{
    var copy_text = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copy_text);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
});`
It still fail :(

Comment: Hello again, looking further into this I've found the following in W3 specs: [Clipboard API and events](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#integration-with-rich-text-editing-apis) Basically it sais that you cannot interact with clipboard instead user triggers the action (clicking a button or so). I think you can't edit users clipboard in document.ready or similar :(

Comment: Hmmmm,  i think about solution add a button to copy that text and do print() to pdf.(and hide that button when click - not print that button)

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome: [Deprecation] The behavior that Selection.addRange() merges existing Range and the specified Range was removed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632 for more details.

Comment: before `addRange()` I had to add `selection.removeAllRanges();` then it worked - tested in Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick hacky way to do what you want, there is a hidden input that we put the data in and then copy it from there. (The text area is just somewhere to paste into)

```js
function copyText(e) {
  var textToCopy = document.querySelector(e);
  var textBox = document.querySelector(".clipboard");
  textBox.setAttribute('value', textToCopy.innerHTML);

  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<h4 class="text" align="center">Text data to copy</h4>

<button onclick="copyText('.text')" class="copy">Copy</button>
<br><br>
<textarea></textarea>

<input class="clipboard hidden" />
```

Comment: `var copy_text = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
var hidden_ = document.createElement("input");
hidden_.setAttribute("class","clipboard hidden");
copy_text.appendChild(hidden_);
copy_text.setAttribute("class","copy_text");
function copyText(e) {
  var textToCopy = document.querySelector(e);
  var textBox = document.querySelector(".clipboard");
  textBox.setAttribute('value', textToCopy.innerHTML);
  textBox.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
copyText(".copy_text");`

Comment: it fail too, i think problem is page loading. All solution (button) success when the page is loaded

Comment: This isn't working for me Also, why not <input type="hidden" /> ?