# How to place html on clipboard that can be pasted into gmail

Tags: html, gmail

In our application, we are generating two URL's that many of our users would like to copy and paste into gmail.  We decided to create HTML code that makes the links look better than the long URL's.  We added a function in our application that places the HTML on the windows clipboard so that they can paste it directly into a gmail compose window.

However, when we paste it into gmail it appears as raw html text.  We searched for solutions and most appear to suggest viewing the html in Chrome, and then copying the results to the clipboard and pasting into gmail. [See This Post](https://www.gmass.co/blog/use-custom-html-in-gmail-compose-window/) We tried this with our source HTML and it worked perfectly, but obviously is not a good solution for our application.

Is there a way that we can write / encode our HTML code directly to the clipboard so that it compatible with gmail?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard might be of interest to you

Comment: I am not sure how this could work with our web application.  Could you provide a little more detail?  Thanks!

Comment: @DougBower have you ever found a good solution? I'm having the exact same issue. I've tried Clipboard API, but it pastes raw HTML into Gmail.

Comment: @dmk12 this works -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216984

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post, but it might help someone.
What I tryied was printing what was actualy on the clipboard before pasting onto gmail to check what is inside. Then I realized gmail reads only when the data is using `html flavor/format` of the clipboard. Then I came up with this to set the hmtl into the clipboard with html format.

**IMPORTANT:** the html must be between these `startfragment` and `endfragment` tags or gmail will not perceive it as html.

Exemple in JAVA:

```
public class SetClipboard  implements ClipboardOwner{

    public SetClipboard() {
        String simpleTable = """
                             <html>
                             <!--StartFragment-->

                             <table>
                               <tr>
                                 <th>COLUMN 1</th>
                                 <th>COLUMN 2</th>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                 <td>ABC</td>
                                 <td>CDE</td>
                               </tr>
                             </table>

                             <!--EndFragment-->
                             </html>
                             """;
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        c.setContents(new TransferableHTML(simpleTable), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {

    }

    private static class TransferableHTML implements Transferable {

        String html;
        public TransferableHTML( String html ) {
            this.html = html;
        }

        public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor )
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if ( flavor.equals( DataFlavor.allHtmlFlavor ) && html != null ) {
                return html;
            }
            else {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
            }
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[ 1 ];
            flavors[ 0 ] = DataFlavor.allHtmlFlavor;
            return flavors;
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor ) {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
            for ( int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++ ) {
                if ( flavor.equals( flavors[ i ] ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SetClipboard();
    }
}
```