# Copy to clipboard takes a tremendous amount of time

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have the following code to copy ~25MB of data to the clipboard:

```
// star time after populating HTML and Text
const start_time = new Date().getTime();
navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
        "text/html": new Blob([html], {
            type: "text/html",
        }),
        "text/plain": new Blob([text], {
            type: "text/plain",
        }),
    }),
]).then(() => {
    // end time after async clipbaord api method is completed
    const end_time = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("writing to clipboard : DONE in", (end_time - start_time) / 1000, "s");
});
```

**And it takes 45s!**

Is there a reason why the `clipboard.write(...)` takes so long to do? Is there some sort of recommendation for how to improve this, or is this just not meant to copy a lot of data?

Comment: Where is the source of the Blob data ? (from a local db or file ? / remote site ? / data feed thru a browser ?)

Comment: @KenLee local data in the browser. Zero network transfer.

Comment: what browser are you using ? (IE ??)

Comment: @KenLee Chrome.

Comment: @KenLee the best way to reproduce might just be to copy some html or xml doc that's about 20MB and use that for the testing.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because they do sanitize your html before appending it to the clipboard, so that if for instance your script tries to insert nefarious scripts as html, it doesn't get executed when the user will paste it in a content-editable element.

Sanitizing 25MB of html takes some time indeed, but that should done in parallel and not block your UI.

Unfortunately StackSnippets sandboxed iframes don't allow the Clipboard API, so here [is a glitch project](https://highfalutin-handy-count.glitch.me/) where you can see the input is indeed sanitized.

Code of the glitch:

```js
btn.onclick = (evt) => {
  const dangerous_content = `<script>alert("I'm bad");<\/script><img src="" onerror="alert('Me too')">`;
  navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
      "text/html": new Blob([dangerous_content, "Hey"], { type: "text/html" })
    })
  ]);
};
document.onpaste = (evt) => {
  log.textContent = `raw "text/html" data from paste event: 
${ evt.clipboardData.getData("text/html") }`;
};
```

Output:

as rich-text: `brokenHey`
as raw markup: `<meta charset='utf-8'><img src="https://highfalutin-handy-count.glitch.me/" alt="broken">Hey`

Comment: I see, but for me it's taking 40s to copy something -- even if it's done async, that's still a terrible user experience (by comparison, doing sync copy takes 1.1s for the same amount of data). Is there any way around that, or other way to do the async copy?

Comment: Well... 25MB is "a lot". Why do you need to copy 25MB of html into the clipboard? Copying or pasting that much data will crash most apps anyway.  Can't you make a download link to an html file instead?